# Getting the names of django object's one-to-many set properties

Tags: python, django, model

I've seen that you can get all the field names from a django model object by calling

```
model_instance._meta.fields
```

But this doesn't include the one-to-many accessors. For example, if I have a House model and a Room model, and a Room has a Foreign key field for House, there is a property on House now called room_set. How can I get a list of these property names for a model instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is the best approach, but it works:

```
from django.db.models.fields.related import ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor
print [prop for prop in dir(House) if isinstance(getattr(House, prop), ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor)]
```

will print:

```
['room_set']
```